# How to pass a parameter to your Controller, through a button click in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, devexpress

May someone assist me with how to tie up my parameters from a combobox to a parameter on one of my action's in my controller. I am using DevExpress control suite and this is my code:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Filter(string filterCriteria)
 {
     ViewData.Model = Repository.GetReports(filterCriteria);
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

And this is my view :

```
<div style="float:right;padding-bottom:20px;" >
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table><tr><td>
Filter by Keyword:</td>
<td>
@Html.DevExpress().DropDownEdit(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "checkComboBox";
        settings.Width = 210;
        settings.Theme = Utils.CurrentTheme;
        settings.Properties.DropDownWindowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0xEDEDED);
        settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.ValueChanged = "function(s, e) {e.customArgs[\"filterCriteria\"] = checkComboBox.Name.toString();}";

        settings.SetDropDownWindowTemplateContent(c =>
        {
            @Html.DevExpress().ListBox(
                listBoxSettings =>
                {
                    listBoxSettings.Name = "checkListBox";
                    listBoxSettings.SkinID = "CheckComboBoxListBox";
                    listBoxSettings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Report", Action = "Filter" };
                    listBoxSettings.Theme = Utils.CurrentTheme;
                    listBoxSettings.ControlStyle.Border.BorderWidth = 2;
                    listBoxSettings.ControlStyle.BorderBottom.BorderWidth = 1;
                    listBoxSettings.ControlStyle.BorderBottom.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0xDCDCDC);
                    listBoxSettings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
                    listBoxSettings.Height = 100;

                    listBoxSettings.Properties.SelectionMode = ListEditSelectionMode.CheckColumn;

                    listBoxSettings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "OnListBoxSelectionChanged";
                }
            ).BindList(Repository.GetKeywords())
            .Render();
            ViewContext.Writer.Write("<table style=\"width:100%\"><tr><td align=\"right\">");
            @Html.DevExpress().Button(
                buttonSettings =>
                {
                    buttonSettings.Name = "buttonClose";
                    buttonSettings.Text = "Close";
                    buttonSettings.Style.Add("float", "right");
                    buttonSettings.Theme = Utils.CurrentTheme;
                    buttonSettings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e){ checkComboBox.HideDropDown(); }";
                }
            )
            .Render();
            ViewContext.Writer.Write("</td></tr></table>");
        });
        settings.Properties.EnableAnimation = true;
        settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.TextChanged = "SynchronizeListBoxValues";
        settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.DropDown = "SynchronizeListBoxValues";
    }
).GetHtml()
</td><td>
@Html.DevExpress().Button(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "btnApply";
        settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
        settings.Text = "Apply";
        settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
        settings.Theme = Utils.CurrentTheme;
        settings.Width = 80;
        settings.RouteValues = new { Controller = "Report", Action = "Filter" };
    }
).GetHtml()
</td><td>
@Html.DevExpress().Button(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "btnClear";
        settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
        settings.Text = "Clear";
        settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e){ ASPxClientEdit.ClearEditorsInContainer(); }";
        settings.Theme = Utils.CurrentTheme;
        settings.Width = 80;
    }
).GetHtml()
</td></tr></table>
}
</div>
```

I have basically a gridview on the bottom  i would like to filter with a drop down list above it. I invoke the action by  using a button to go filter my collection. In this example, i was just trying to pass back the name of the control, i.e.

```
settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.ValueChanged = "function(s, e) {e.customArgs[\"filterCriteria\"] = checkComboBox.Name.toString();}";
```

just to see if I am able to pass back any value but this failed. Can someone please elaborate on a way to do this?Thank you,

Comment: I think the best way would be through a Jquery call. Would you be interested in this option ?

Comment: Where are the rest of the options for your @Html.BeginForm??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather, you want to retrieve the multiple items selected within the "checkListBox" ListBox on the Controller side.
If so, use the [ListBoxExtension.GetSelectedValues](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebMvcListBoxExtension_GetSelectedValues%5BT%5Dtopic) method in the following manner:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Filter(string filterCriteria)
{
    //listBoxSettings.Name = "checkListBox";

    string[] values = ListBoxExtension.GetSelectedValues<string>("checkListBox");
    filterCriteria = values...

    ViewData.Model = Repository.GetReports(filterCriteria);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but thought I might just add the use of `viewbag` which allows you to send data from controller to view, and vice versa. Here is an example from [mdsn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx).

**controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.MyMessageToUsers = "Hello from me.";
    ViewBag.AnswerText = "Your answer goes here.";

    return View();
}
```

**view**

```
@ViewBag.MyMessageToUsers
@Html.TextBox("AnswerText")
```